# implementing countdown timer with user input

Tags: android

i am trying to implement a countdown timer that starts from the number that the user inputs in the EditText. When i am running my program with the emulator, i realise that something goes wrong inside the countdown timer block since it does not enter inside this block.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText countDownTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText intervalTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    int interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("buttonpressed", "interval  countdown equals " + interval);

                    new CountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()), 1000) {

                        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
                            Log.d("counttimer1", "enter");
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                       countDownTxt.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                }
                            });
                               countDownTxt.setText(""+ millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                            }



                        public void onFinish() {
                            countDownTxt.setText("done!");
                        }
                     }.start();

                    }
            }
    );
```

Any suggestions on solving this problemt ?

Comment: Which block? onTick? How much do you enter into the the EditText for time?

Comment: Yes, onTick(). It does not print even this: Log.d("counttimer1", "enter");          I am entering an integer number like: 6

Comment: The issue is that i know, the number in the Countdown timer must be long. but i made instead of Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()) this one Long.parseLong(intervalTxt.getText().toString()) but nothing changed!

Answer (score 3):

try using this

```
    long timeVal = Long.parseLong(intervalTxt.getText().toString());
    new CountDownTimer(timeVal, 1000) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entered number by user present seconds, you should have like:

```
int time = Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()) * 1000;

new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

...
```

Comment: Thankssss!!!! its now working :) also, i want to ask a suggestion from you on how to add more timers in one application, like to have multiple timers !

Comment: same way you create this one, they are all independent objects.